# NHibernate Criteria API with unmapped tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria-api

I have a class with corresponding mapping as below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; private set; }
    //...
    public virtual List<int> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PatientId)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        HasMany(x => x.Orders)
            .Element("OrderId", t => t.Type<int>())
            .Table("CustomerOrder")
            .KeyColumn("CustomerId")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Customer_Order")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Assume class Order is in another database, so I can't map it in this assembly. (I'm not sure this is the best way of doing this, please feel free to comment on the mapping too.)

So I would like to be able to find Customers with more than N orders, SQL query would look like this:

```
select * from Customer c where
    (select count(*) from orders where CutsomerId = c.CustomerId) > N
```

What would be Criteria API equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

As another option could you not just add an `OrderCount` property to your Customer class so you don't need the join to the other DB.

Anything you do which joins cross DB or joins to unmapped classes feels a bit wrong.

Comment: I guess so, but since the option exists to create a list of ints as a property, there should be a way to query it.